# Hacker rank questions on finding the odd number

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-allocation

I am trying to do a hacker rank question. The question is simple. But it has asked me to do it using static allocation and dynamic allocation and every other simple question like finding an odd number asks me to use allocation while doing it from C? I just need someone who has encountered this in hacker rank and tells me if it is the way it is or am I not understanding something.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* readline();
char* ltrim(char*);
char* rtrim(char*);

int parse_int(char*);



/*
 * Complete the 'findNumber' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return a STRING.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. INTEGER_ARRAY arr
 *  2. INTEGER k
 */

/*
 * To return the string from the function, you should either do static allocation or dynamic allocation
 *
 * For example,
 * char* return_string_using_static_allocation() {
 *     static char s[] = "static allocation of string";
 *
 *     return s;
 * }
 *
 * char* return_string_using_dynamic_allocation() {
 *     char* s = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
 *
 *     s = "dynamic allocation of string";
 *
 *     return s;
 * }
 *
 */
char* findNumber(int arr_count, int* arr, int k) {

}

int main()
{
    FILE* fptr = fopen(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"), "w");

    int arr_count = parse_int(ltrim(rtrim(readline())));

    int* arr = malloc(arr_count * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_count; i++) {
        int arr_item = parse_int(ltrim(rtrim(readline())));

        *(arr + i) = arr_item;
    }

    int k = parse_int(ltrim(rtrim(readline())));

    char* result = findNumber(arr_count, arr, k);

    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", result);

    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}

char* readline() {
    size_t alloc_length = 1024;
    size_t data_length = 0;

    char* data = malloc(alloc_length);

    while (true) {
        char* cursor = data + data_length;
        char* line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);

        if (!line) {
            break;
        }

        data_length += strlen(cursor);

        if (data_length < alloc_length - 1 || data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
            break;
        }

        alloc_length <<= 1;

        data = realloc(data, alloc_length);

        if (!data) {
            data = '\0';

            break;
        }
    }

    if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
        data[data_length - 1] = '\0';

        data = realloc(data, data_length);

        if (!data) {
            data = '\0';
        }
    } else {
        data = realloc(data, data_length + 1);

        if (!data) {
            data = '\0';
        } else {
            data[data_length] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return data;
}

char* ltrim(char* str) {
    if (!str) {
        return '\0';
    }

    if (!*str) {
        return str;
    }

    while (*str != '\0' && isspace(*str)) {
        str++;
    }

    return str;
}

char* rtrim(char* str) {
    if (!str) {
        return '\0';
    }

    if (!*str) {
        return str;
    }

    char* end = str + strlen(str) - 1;

    while (end >= str && isspace(*end)) {
        end--;
    }

    *(end + 1) = '\0';

    return str;
}

int parse_int(char* str) {
    char* endptr;
    int value = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);

    if (endptr == str || *endptr != '\0') {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what your issue is. `findNumber` should return a pointer to a buffer with *static* **OR** *allocated* [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration), which the comment above its definition explains rather explicitly. The caller does not provide a buffer, so you must make sure the returned data has a [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) that extends beyond your function. What *specific* problem are you having in implementing either of these?

Comment: Why is there a need to open a file for this? We can see its opening a file for this.